# constant INADDR_NONE in delphi

Tags: delphi, winsock

This is an example of my code:

```
Result.S_addr := inet_addr(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(Address)));
if Result.S_addr = INADDR_NONE then
begin
  // codigo;
end;
```

'Result.S_addr' return -1 becouse 'Address' is an url. INADDR_NONE is a constant define in WINAPI as 'DWORD($FFFFFFFF)'. 
In theory should enter the IF statement, but INADDR_NONE takes the value 4294967295 (decimal) so it never enters the IF statement.
Why takes that value? and How I can do to make the constant taking the appropriate value?

thanks guys.

PD: I'm using RAD Studio 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is one of declarations in Winsock.

`S_addr` is declared as `u_long`, but unfortunately, `u_long` is defined as signed `Longint` instead of unsigned `Longword`. So you should cast:

```
if Result.S_addr = u_long(INADDR_NONE) then
begin
  ...
end;
```

Comment: In WinSock2  `u_long = Cardinal;`. Is it possible just to use WinSock2 instead of WinSock?

Comment: Winsock2 is for the winsock2.dll, not sure if they are interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks, it works. At the moment works using WinSock and WinSock2. 
I hope there are no problems with any of them (v1.1 - v2.2)

Comment: `Winsock2` replaces `Winsock`, it is a drop-in replacement.